# Prove that if T is injective and $\{v_i\}$ is linearly independent, then $\{Tv_i\}$ is also linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: V \to V$ be a linear operator.

- Prove that if T is injective and $\{v_i\}$ is linearly independent, then $\{Tv_i\}$ is also linearly independent.
- Prove that if T is surjective and $\{v_i\}$ spans V, then $\{Tv_i\}$ also spans V.

**Proof of 1:** Assume that T is injective and $\{v_i\}$ is linearly independent. By definitions,

- A linear operation T is called injective if $x=0$ whenever $Tx=0$. (i.e. If $Tx=0$ then $x=0$)
- $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^k$ is linearly independent if the only set of scalars $\{ c_1, c_2, \dots, c_k\}$ which gives $\sum_{i=1}^k c_iv_i=0$ is the zero set $c_1=c_2=\dots=c_k=0$.
  \end{itemize}

We need to show that $\{Tv_i\}_{i=1}^k$ is linearly independent if the only set of scalars $\{ a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k\}$ which gives $\sum_{i=1}^k a_iTv_i=0$ is the zero set $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_k=0$.

**How do I apply the definitions?**

**Proof of 2:** What do it mean $\{ v_i \}$ spans V?

Answer (score 2):

It means that for any $v \in V$, there are scalars $r_i's$ such that: $v = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k r_iv_i$. Thus for part b), let $w \in V$, then since $\{v_i\}$ spans $V$, and $T$ is onto,  we have: $w = T(v) = T\left(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k r_iv_i\right)$. So: $w = T(v) = T\left(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k r_iv_i\right) = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k r_iT(v_i)$, proving that $\{T(v_i)\}$ spans $V$ as well.

Comment: How do I finish the first proof?

Comment: I just added the proof of part b.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so let's check which scalars make $\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{k} \alpha_{i} T(v_{i})$ equal to $0$.

Note that $T$ is linear, so we know $\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{k} \alpha_{i} T(v_{i}) = T(\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{k} \alpha_{i}v_{i})$, and we want to know which $\alpha_{i}$ make this equal to $0$.

So we want to know for which $\alpha_{i}$ is $T(\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{k} \alpha_{i}v_{i}) = 0$.  But $T$ is injective, and by your definition, that means we must have:

$T(\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{k} \alpha_{i}v_{i}) = 0 \implies \sum \limits_{i = 1}^{k} \alpha_{i}v_{i} = 0$.

Finally, since $v_{i}$'s are linearly independent, we know that the only scalars that make the $v_{i}$'s all combine to equal $0$ are the scalars that are all equal to $0$.  So this means we must have $\alpha_{i} = 0$ for all $i$.

But this means the only scalar solution to $\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{k} \alpha_{i} T(v_{i}) = 0$ is when all of the $\alpha_{i}$'s are $0$, which is precisely what it means for the set $\{ T(v_{i}) \}$ to be linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Letting $W=\{w\in V: w=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}v_{i}\}$, when we say that $\{v_{i}\}$ spans $V$ we are saying that $W=V$. Well notice that if $T$ is surjective we have $T(V)=V$, thus we have $T(W)=V$. Well notice that $T(W)=\{w\in V: w=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}T(v_{i})\}$ which means that $T(W)$ is span of $\{T(v_{i})\}$. Thus we have the span of $\{T(v_i)\}$ is $V$